# Lost the shift+← and shift+→ key combinations

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, keyboard

On my laptop I have somehow lost the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> key combinations.

## Setup:

- Ubuntu 12.10 OS
- Windows 7 running in Virtual box
- Synergyc running on the Linux Host
- Connected to Synergys running on my desktop machine, also running Ubuntu 12.10

## Info

The key mappings are fine in Linux. This has happened following an install of vsvim inside of Visual Studio 2012.  Now globally inside this particular Virtual Box instance I can no longer use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

Funnily enough when I go to the VS Key mapping finder it shows me that:

- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

I have asked in Super User as this is also affecting the Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Visual Studio in admin mode it will take over all global key mappings.